# How to bind a XDocument object to a Treeview without using codebehind?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, treeview, linq-to-xml

I try to bind an XDocument object to a treeview without using any codebehind so it is conform the MVVM pattern. So far I haven't figured out how to do that yet. I searched a lot and saw many questions about XDocuments and treeviews but none of them really helped, most of them did have code behind or didnt explain (clearly) how to do it.

I thought it would be easy as

```
<treeview ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TheXDocumentObject, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

but my treelist stays empty (and I am 100% sure the XML file is loaded in the XDocument like it should be). I also found the XmlDataProvider but the Source of it doesnt allow databinding because it isnt a DependencyProperty or DependencyObject.

So I am a bit stuck here, what do I need to do to bind an XDocument object to the treeview without having codebehind? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't be possible without code behind or a converter (or some code in your view model.) XDocument is for LINQ to Xml, there is no collection property on it as you are reading through the document and not a public collection of xmlnodes. You may be able to do this with an XmlDocumdnt and a HierarchicalDataTemplate (without using any c#)

Comment: Based on searching on the internet and the low useful search results I feared the fact that it wasn't possible. You are talking about a converter, what do you mean by that? An own class structure where the class structure matches the element structure in the XML document and bind the class structure to the tree or is there a better way to convert the XDocument to an object that can be bind to the treeview?

Comment: You can write an IValueConverter see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx

You bind to a value in xaml, set this as the converter in the binding and it will return results. What you can do is write a converter so that it will evaluate the XDocument and return a collection of XmlNodes. From then, you can use your own ItemTemplate to display it how you want.